# Problem installing .apk downloaded from .net web service

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services

Scenario: I am downloading a file from asp.net web service in to my android application. The web Service returns a byte array. I am able to download file to specific location. But when I run it in Android it is giving the message:

> "Problem parsing a package"

Here is my web service code and And Android code:

**Web Service code:**

```
    [WebMethod]
        public byte[] GetApkFile(string deviceID)
        {
                try
                {
                        string path = "D:\\Users\\CHAITANYA\\Documents";
                        string fileName = path + "\\sample.apk";
                        FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileName);
                        return ConvertStreamToByteBuffer(fileStream);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                        throw ex;

            }

        }

        public byte[] ConvertStreamToByteBuffer(System.IO.Stream theStream)
        {
                int b1;
                System.IO.MemoryStream tempStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                while ((b1 = theStream.ReadByte()) != -1)
                {
                        tempStream.WriteByte(((byte)b1));
            }
                    return tempStream.ToArray();
        }
```

**Android code:**

```
    package com.example.dwnload;

    import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.MarshalBase64;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class FileDownloadActivity extends Activity 
    {
            /** Called when the activity is first created. */

        TextView tv;
        Button dwnload;

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
            {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.main);
                    dwnload=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
                    tv=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    dwnload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {

                public void onClick(View arg0)
                {

                    TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                            String deviceId = TelephonyMgr.getDeviceId(); 
                            String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetApkFile";       
                            String METHOD_NAME = "GetApkFile";
                            String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
                            final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/Dashboard/Service.asmx";

                            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
                            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                            //new MarshalBase64().register(envelope); 
                            envelope.encodingStyle = SoapEnvelope.ENC;
                            request.addProperty("deviceID", deviceId);  
                            //tv.setText(deviceId.toString());
                            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                            envelope.dotNet = true;
                            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                            HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                            try 
                            {
                                httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                                //SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
                                Object response = envelope.getResponse();
                                byte[] b=response.toString().getBytes();
                                String s = new String(b);

                                try 
                                {
                                            String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/myappdir/" + "sample.apk" ;

                                                          File file = new File(filePath);
                                            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                                            file.createNewFile();

                                            BufferedOutputStream objectOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                                            objectOut.write(b);
                                            objectOut.close();

                                           }
                                catch (Exception e) 
                                {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                }



                        }   


                            catch (Exception exception) 
                            {
                                exception.toString();           
                            }
                }
            });
                } 



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a line there on android

```
byte[] b=response.toString().getBytes();
```

which should be replaced by

```
byte[] b=Base64.decode(response.toString());
```

because soap envelop will encode it to <base64Binary> 
and don't forget to `import org.kobjects.base64.Base64;`

Just found something out about the .net part. Your file reading method doesn't transfer the file correctly... intead of ReadByte I used Read and passed the array (as reference) and then returned the array with the correct data:

```
[WebMethod]
public byte[] GetApk()
{
    string file = "file name goes here";
    FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(file);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)stream.Length);

    return buffer;
}
```

worked for me... now my app can auto-update ;)
I hope it works for you too

Comment: i have tried those steps what you have mentioned.i am getting the response but with sbytes(-) and so i have parse error while installing the apk.Need help !!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you follow a few debugging steps.

First verify that your webservice is working as expected.
You can do this by write a .net based client that will download your file and write it to disk. You can do a binary compare to see you are getting the intended file.

If you do get the file as expected, your webservice is working fine.

Now compare this file to the one downloaded using android.

This should help you isolate the error.

Comment: Okay,As indicated by you..i will follow above debugging steps..thanks!